# How to use Facebook registration plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, facebook

Hi, I want to implement **sign in with Facebook** in my Rails web application. I red about it from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/.

My problem is I am not getting how to get the users data from signed request into my database.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

this is the iframe code change the client_id and redirect_url with yours client id and redirect_url

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&
             redirect_uri=MY_REDIRECT_URI&
             fields=name,email,first_name,last_name"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
</iframe>
```

it will automatically call the redirect_url provided here after clicking the register . in that method facebook will return you one variable "signed_request" that contains all the data for users. in the method you can decode the signed request .  this is my code to decode the signed request

```
def decode_facebook_hash(signed_request)
  signature, str = signed_request.split('.')
  str += '=' * (4 - str.length.modulo(4))
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Base64.decode64(str.gsub("-", "+").gsub("_", "/")))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OmniAuth` gem.

A railscast tutorial is available here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Comment: I know about how to embed the registration plugin in my web application & I want to know about how to get the logged in users information?

Comment: Then you'll have to edit and be a lot more explicit in your question. What information do you want, exactly? You can get user information in a console using `User.first` but I imagine that's not what you want so define what you want better.

Comment: Oh first of all sorry & thanks you for replying. Just see these links  1.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/  Fill your facebook account details and  when you will click on register you will be redirected to 2.https://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo/ I want the data in signed request.Thank you.